# Using twitter's bootstrap in jsFiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, minify, jsfiddle

I would like to use [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) in one of my fiddles. Since [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) does not offer bootstrap as one of its pre-defined libraries, I am looking for a minified url.

Is there a free minified URL for Twitter's Bootstrap?

Comment: You think this would be something they'd add, right?

Comment: Take a look at http://bootply.com Bootstrap and other plugins can be included

Answer (score 40, accepted):

<s>have a look at jsfiddle</s>

@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

**UPDATE**

import css or js files from **external resources** of jsfiddle

you can use *[bootstrapcdn](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)* with specific version of bootstrap e.g **2.3.2** instead of **3.1.1**

CSS : `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`

JS : `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js`

working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/) for v3.1.1

Comment: This URL no longer works, and if it did, is version independent so it might not work later on. @mlctrez's Bootstrap CDN answer gives you a versioned URL so it'll work later on, and you can modify the URL to find older versions (e.g., //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css).

Answer (score 13):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/241/

using external resources 
`http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css
 http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/js/bootstrap.min.js`

** Below Method No More Working but kept if someday something changes**

As of now select jquery 2.1.0  then you will get bootstrap as an option

Bootstrap 3.2.0
Bootstrap 2.3.2

[image]

Answer (score 11):

For Bootstrap 3 with included CSS and JS look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)

```
CSS: //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
JS: //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

**Upd:** add version [3.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/240/) and [latest version](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/241/)

Answer (score 7):

Try this Content Delivery Network url. It has links to the minified CSS and Javascript.
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative to jsFiddle for Bootstrap is:

http://www.bootply.com/new