# Bootstrap 3, how to reduce the padding of text in input element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I apply the Bootstrap 3 style to my edit form. However, I want to reduce the padding of the input box and font-size.

Because of this, it make my edit form larger.
I tried to change the grid column class (col-sm-*,col-md-*), but it didn't help.

And also override the **css**, it make the input box doesn't show the text.

```css
.form-horizontal .form-group input, 
.form-horizontal .form-group select,
.form-horizontal .form-group label { 
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtProductName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="txtProductName" CssClass="form-control"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using col-*-* outside of the row tag? This can and probably will break the paddings/margins. And why are they set to different screens?(sm and md).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overall I do not recommend overriding the responsive grid in bootstrap as that is the main reason to be using it!

To override the form styling just use the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtProductName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="txtProductName" Class="form-control form-fixer"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input.form-fixer {
    padding: 1px;
    font-size: 19px;
}

.form-horizontal .form-group input, 
.form-horizontal .form-group select,
.form-horizontal .form-group label
 { 
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

Also have a Jsfiddle set up....
http://jsfiddle.net/ZRosenbauer/4wDKp/

Comment: You might want to do a padding: 1px 3px; instead. cause it is a bit too close to left

Comment: You can add bootstrap into fiddle without the need to copy and past all boostrap css: [Using twitter's bootstrap in jsFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251586/using-twitters-bootstrap-in-jsfiddle)